# Possible to have multiple SqlCommand?

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlcommand

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Database=Clinic_Management_System;Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Clinic Management System.mdf")
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
conn.Open()
cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO record([PatientID],[Prescription],[VisitDate]) Values ('" & PatientIDTextBox.Text & "','" & txtPrescription.Text & "',GetDate()) ", conn)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

For cn As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO record_item([RecordID],[ItemID],[Amount]) Values ( (SELECT MAX(RecordID) FROM record)," & DataGridView1.Rows(cn).Cells(0).Value & "," & DataGridView1.Rows(cn).Cells(2).Value & ")", conn)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Next
conn.Close()
```

Is this possible to run 2 `SqlCommand` together??

Because after executed somehow the 2nd inside the loop did not execute or insert data.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Have you tried debugging? What happens at the 2nd `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`?

Comment: nothing error, after debug and try to insert some data, but database remain empty, only 1st sqlcommand worked

Comment: Does your DataGrid have rows?

Comment: yes...now i doubt maybe the command isn't correct

Answer (score 2):

You don't have 2 SqlCommands.

You have 1 SqlCommand, called `cmd`, which is executed multiple times.

It is fine to do something like this, however I would have 1 SqlCommand for your `INSERT INTO record`, and 1 for your `INSERT INTO record_item`. I think this makes it much easier to understand when looking back at the code at a later date.

Either way, using a SqlCommand like this should not prevent it from executing, therefore I believe there is another issue with your scripting.

---

I've adapted your code so that it is split into 2 seperate SqlCommand objects, and the queries have been parameterized to prevent SQL Injection:

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Database=Clinic_Management_System;Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Clinic Management System.mdf")

Dim cmdRecord As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO record ([PatientID],[Prescription],[VisitDate]) Values (@PatientID, @Prescription, GETDATE())", conn)
cmdRecord.Parameters.Add("@PatientID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PatientIDTextBox.Text
cmdRecord.Parameters.Add("@Prescription", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPrescription.Text

Dim cmdRecordItem As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO record_item([RecordID],[ItemID],[Amount]) Values ( (SELECT MAX(RecordID) FROM record),@ItemID,@AmountID)", conn)
cmdRecordItem.Parameters.Add("@ItemID", SqlDbType.Int)
cmdRecordItem.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.Decimal)

Dim dr As SqlDataReader
conn.Open()

cmdRecord.ExecuteNonQuery()

For cn As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    cmdRecordItem.Parameters("@ItemID").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(cn).Cells(0).Value
    cmdRecordItem.Parameters("@Amount").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(cn).Cells(2).Value

    cmdRecordItem.ExecuteNonQuery()

Next
conn.Close()
```

Comment: The OP only has one SqlCommand variable, but actually creates multiple SqlCommand *objects*. There are two new SqlCommand() assignments, and one is in a loop.

Comment: This is true, but the new SqlCommand object might as well just be a change to the `CommandText`, as everything else is remaining the same.

Comment: Yes, absolutely... but your answer says he only has one SqlCommand.

Comment: thanks for the code, i just realise, the problem is 
Dim cmdRecordItem As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO record_item([RecordID],[ItemID],[Amount]) Values ( (SELECT MAX(RecordID) FROM record),@ItemID,@AmountID)", conn)

even though i set default value for this 3 items, the value also cannot store inside the database,don't know why...i checked the name,column name all correct

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure that either all statements complete successfully or that none do, you need to wrap your commands in a transaction.

Using parameters for the commands will also make the code more understandable and safer and you should use using statements where possible.

Also, performing the Select max recordid is a very bad idea (if you have multiple users), but I'll leave that for another time:

```
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Database=Clinic_Management_System;Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Clinic Management System.mdf")
        Dim cmdRecord As SqlCommand
        Dim cmdRecordItem As SqlCommand
        Dim oTran As SqlTransaction = Nothing

        conn.Open()
        Try
            cmdRecord = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO record([PatientID],[Prescription],[VisitDate]) Values (@PatientID, @Prescription, GetDate())", conn)
            cmdRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientID", PatientIDTextBox.Text)
            cmdRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prescription", txtPrescription.Text)

            cmdRecordItem = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO record_item([RecordID],[ItemID],[Amount]) SELECT ISNULL(MAX(RecordID), 0), @ItemID, @Amount FROM record", conn)
            cmdRecordItem.Parameters.Add("@ItemId")
            cmdRecordItem.Parameters.Add("@Amount")

            oTran = conn.BeginTransaction

            cmdRecord.ExecuteNonQuery()

            For Each oRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1
                cmdRecordItem.Parameters("@ItemId").Value = oRow.Cells(0).Value
                cmdRecordItem.Parameters("@Amount").Value = oRow.Cells(2).Value

                cmdRecordItem.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next

            oTran.Commit()
        Catch
            If oTran IsNot Nothing Then
                oTran.Rollback()
            End If

            Throw
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Using
```

Comment: this code somehow also not working, like you said, either all complete, or none do

Comment: @user1151874: Are there any exceptions being thrown? I have updated the insert record_item to use a different query format in case that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One command can only be used once.
If you want to use more than one command, declare a new `cmd` as

```
Dim cmd2 as SqlCommand
```